# Generate P2WSH native

Tags: segregated-witness, witness-data, p2wsh

I want to create P2WSH native like https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0173.
I have already a script to generate P2WPKH and it works, thank the python part and re-arrange group byte works.

I read that witnessScript (scriptPubKey) is hash of SHA256 without RIPEMD160.
Below a little bit of my code.

```
PB=0279BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798

#REDEEM SCRIPT <Public Key> OP_CHECKSIG
SCRIPT=210279BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798AC

#SCRIPT HASH
$ printf $SCRIPT | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256| sed 's/^.* //'
1863143c14c5166804bd19203356da136c985678cd4d27a1b8c6329604903262

Convert scripthash to base 2
```

> 11000 01100 01100 01010 00011 11000 00101 00110 00101 00010 11001 10100 00000 01001 01111 01000 11001 00100 00000 11001 10101 01101
>   10110 10000 10011 01101 10010 01100 00101 01100 11110 00110 01101
>   01001 10100 10011 11010 00011 01110 00110 00110 00110 01010 01011
>   00000 01001 00100 00001 10010 01100 010

I need to add two zero at the beginning in order to Re-arrange those bits into groups of 5

> 00110 00011 00011 00010 10000 11110 00001 01001 10001 01000 10110
>   01101 00000 00010 01011 11010 00110 01001 00000 00110 01101 01011
>   01101 10100 00100 11011 01100 10011 00001 01011 00111 10001 10011
>   01010 01101 00100 11110 10000 11011 10001 10001 10001 10010 10010
>   11000 00010 01001 00000 01100 10011 00010

Add witness program

> 00000 00110 00011 00011 00010 10000 11110 00001 01001 10001 01000 10110
>   01101 00000 00010 01011 11010 00110 01001 00000 00110 01101 01011
>   01101 10100 00100 11011 01100 10011 00001 01011 00111 10001 10011
>   01010 01101 00100 11110 10000 11011 10001 10001 10001 10010 10010
>   11000 00010 01001 00000 01100 10011 00010

Convert each bits to base10

```
0, 6, 3, 3, 2, 16, 30, 1, 9, 17, 8, 22, 13, 0, 2, 11, 26, 6, 9, 0, 6, 13, 11, 13, 20, 4, 27, 12, 19, 1, 11, 7, 17, 19, 10, 13, 4, 30, 16, 27, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 24, 2, 9, 0, 12, 19, 2
```

Create the checksum with python code

```
15
29
21
28
10
6
```

my result is:

```
tb1qxrrzs7pf3gkdqzt6xfqxdtd5ymvnpt83n2dy7sm333jjczfqvnz0a4u2x
```

but the result in BIP 0173 is

```
tb1qrp33g0q5c5txsp9arysrx4k6zdkfs4nce4xj0gdcccefvpysxf3q0sl5k7
```

I use the same script to generate P2WPKH that you can find in BIP_173 and it works. Of course I change Public key with public key hash, but the logic of create group of 5 bits and python part is the same.

Another question: can I create these address (P2WPKH and P2SH native) from bitcoin-cli?

Comment: The data encoded using 8->5 bit conversion is not the entire scriptPubKey, just the witness program itself (=the 32 bytes coming out of SHA256). You then prefix it with a 'q' (for witness version 0).

Comment: thanks for reply, but I don't understand sorry. Now I use Public key to generate group of 5 bits. You mean use the SHA256 of `SCRIPTPUBKEY`? In that way I have the same problem, I don't receive the right result. thanks

Comment: You're converting the entire scriptPubKey to groups of 5 bits. You're only supposed to convert the script hash (this is also the case with P2WPKH, except with ripemd160(sha256(pubkey)) instead of sha256(script)).

Comment: Script is `SCRIPT=210279BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798AC` script hash is `1863143c14c5166804bd19203356da136c985678cd4d27a1b8c6329604903262` scriptPubKey is: `00201863143c14c5166804bd19203356da136c985678cd4d27a1b8c6329604903262`

Then I convert to base2 the scripthash `1863143c14c5166804bd19203356da136c985678cd4d27a1b8c6329604903262` but I can't get the right result

Comment: Ok, that sounds correct. I was confused by your first "00000" 5-bit group that came out. I don't have time right now to go into more detail, but perhaps someone else will.

Comment: Your mistake is in bech32 encoding (the part of the code you removed from your post). The hash being `1863...` makes your bits be like this (first item is witver) `00000 00011 00001 10001 1...` which are `0,3,1,17,...` as integers that makes chars as `q,r,p,3,...` that is the same as correct address `tb1qrp3...`

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast thanks for your reply, I updated my question. I don't understand why I should to have 00011, i need to add just two zeros at the beginning. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bech32 encoding, apart from the checksum, is a simple matter of converting base-256 (8-bits) to base-32 (5-bits). Base-256 is the byte array (octet string) that you get from a hash function. Only focusing on first 3 bytes of the hash:

```
as hex    = 0x18     0x63     0x14 
as bytes  = 24       99       20 
as binary = 00011000 01100011 00010100
```

In order to convert the above base-256 (8-bits) input to base-32 (5-bits) we start from the most significant bit and select 5 bits at a time until we run out.

```
12345123 45123451 23451234 ...
00011000 01100011 00010100
(00011) (00001) (10001) (10001) (0100 ...
```

For a bech-32 *address* there is an extra step here **after the base conversion is done**. That step is to append of the "witness version" to the beginning of this group as an already converted value in base-32 (since witness version is defined from 0 to 16 inclusive it is already in range).

```
[00000] (00011) (00001) (10001) (10001) (0100 ...
```

This final result can be converted to an array of *numbers* that are between 0 and 31

```
0, 3, 1, 17, 17
```

To convert this "number" array to human readable format we print the corresponding character from the bech32 charset (`qpzry9x8gf2tvdw0s3jn54khce6mua7l`)

```
0->q, 3->r, 1->p, 17->3, 17->3 ...
```

P.S. There is a checksum calculation that I skipped to keep it simple but it is just another appended set of 5-bit values at the *end* of what we have in last step.

Comment: oh thanks, I just convert SHA256 digest into base2. it's not enough?
```SCRIPT_HASH=`printf $SCRIPT | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256| sed 's/^.* //'```
Then convert to base2```echo "ibase=16; obase=2; $(echo $SCRIPT_HASH | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') " | bc  | sed 's/\\//g' | tr -d '\n' > base2.txt```

Comment: that command is not correct echo `'ibase=16; obase=2; 18' | bc`? I use the same logic and script for P2WPKH and same logic to calculate Seed phrase. thanks again

Comment: I can generate P2WPKH without a problem with same logic, even your post in bitcoin talk (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4992632.0). the P2WSH logic about Base2 is different?

Comment: I can't understand the code you posted so I can't tell which part of it is wrong. But you may be having a bug that works with 20 bytes input but not with 32. There is a padding involved when converting bits (20 byte = 160 bit % 5 = *0* but 32 byte = 256 bit % 5 = *1*).

Comment: Enthusuast. Thanks for your time, it's very funny because with 20 byte it works. Anyway maybe I find a bug, but I have a new problem with checksum (in 20 byte is ok obviously)